# Why do Swiss road border crossings differ in setup?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, switzerland

Having crossed the Swiss border at numerous locations by bus, I've observed that they use totally different setups.

Setup 1: at [this crossing](https://www.google.ch/maps/@47.5489506,7.757022,799m/data=!3m1!1e3), Germany and Switzerland each has a separate one-way checkpoint, meaning a border check may be done by the country of entry, but not the country of exit.

Setup 2: at [this crossing](https://www.google.ch/maps/place/74100+Annemasse,+Frankreich/@46.1482166,6.093945,809m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x478c6e2a0aae266b:0x9c5b0362feb46ded!8m2!3d46.193253!4d6.234158), both Switzerland and France have checkpoints in both directions, meaning you may be checked twice in both directions (which has also happened to me once)

Setup 3 (most common): [this crossing](https://www.google.ch/maps/@47.6568805,9.159906,198m/data=!3m1!1e3) has a common Swiss/German checkpoint, meaning you could theoretically be checked by each country at the same location. In practice, I've only been checked by the country of entry at this type of crossing, but don't know if it varies.

What is the reason behind the difference between the crossings?

Comment: @pnuts Any idea where on StackExchange it could be on-topic?

Comment: Switzerland is not part of the EEA. So you should _normally_ see only customs checks at these crossings. But I think you already knew that....

Comment: I like the question and have observed the same phenomenon. I am familiar with the Basil control point and the exit to France and the exit to Italy. I hope this question finds a home, ping me when it does, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Officially yes, **not** true in reality. The Swiss specifically **do** regularly perform pure immigration checks at the land border, especially for bus passengers (but without stamps of course, and usually only on entry). The others do it as well, but much more rarely

Comment: What I REALLY want to know is how to remove the sticker; because it leaves an ugly white residue on windscreen! Horrible pain!

Comment: @GayotFow isopropyl alcohol to remove the residue? Dampen a rag with it, lay it on the residue, leave it for a minute or so, wipe it away, should be done. If something is still there deploy a plastic scraper or knife.

Comment: @chx yeah and that abrasion damages whatever it is that they coat the wind screen with so it will not shatter.

Comment: owie. well then let's just use the alchohol. but also.. don't you need to scrape the screen for ice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer regarding some other European borders, **history and available building space**.

Once upon a time, a normal border crossing would consist of two checkpoints, each on their side of the border, with a barrier pole in between. Each nation did their own thing. With increasingly good relations in Europe, checkpoints got rebuild as a single building on the border, with offices for both sides and no pole.

Of course that would require a rebuilding of the checkpoints, and an agreement to let **armed agents of a foreign government** to enter a sovereign nation. There is still no universal agreement in this regard, just a mixture of binational agreements.

For instance, in the 70s a motorist would *stop* at the border between Germany and the Netherlands. The driver would hand the passports through the window. Often the border guards would merely *count* the passports and the passengers and then return the papers. They had the option to check them, of course.

In the 80s a motorist would *slow* to a walking pace and press the passports to the closed car window. The border guards would either wave the car on or signal to stop.

In the 90s the checkpoints were gone from many borders that were both EU and Schengen internal. The buildings got demolished, the real estate sold. So for a temporary spot check, it had to be set up at the last highway exit before the border -- it could be several km from the actual border. There was a time when customs and police could cross borders in hot pursuit, but not to get to their workplace, which made things even messier.

Comment: @pnuts, I'm explaining that border checkpoints are constrained by existing buildings and available real estate. They cannot be rebuilt each time the rules change.

Comment: Note that example 3 shows a small German peninsula surrounded by Swiss countryside. From an urban planning perspective it makes sense to put the German checkpoint into Switzerland.